# Initialize add_action() for every copy of a specific shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I have here a shortcode which generate a slider. Everything works just fine until i try to add another "partners" slider with different options. I can't specific settings for each slider because the print_partners_scripts() function is generated only once. I need to initialize print_partners_scripts() function for every slider with specified in shortcode options. I hope you understand what i mean ;)

```
function print_partners_scripts() {
    global $extra_options, $pslider;
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">' . "\n";
    echo 'jQuery(document).ready( function() {'. "\n";
    echo '  $(".'.$pslider.'").bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 924,
        auto: 1,
        autoStart: 1,
        moveSlides: 1,
        minSlides: 7,
        maxSlides: 8,
        pager: false,
        controls: false,
        slideMargin: 5,
        autoHover: true
        ' . $extra_options . '
        });' . "\n";
    echo '});' . "\n";
    echo '</script>' . "\n";
}

function partners($atts ) {
    global $extra_options, $pslider;
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(  
            'ids' => null,
            'extra_options' => null
        ), $atts));  

    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'print_partners_scripts' );
    $pslider = 'partners-slider'.rand(100,999);
    $ids = explode( ',', $ids );
    $output = '<div class="section row-one"><div class="col ps-gradient"><div class="ps-wrap"><div class="'.$pslider.'">';
    foreach($ids as $id) {    
    $img_attr = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, 'full' );
    $alt_text = get_post_meta( $id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
    $output .= '<div class="pslide"><a href="' . $alt_text . '"><img src="' . $img_attr[0] . '" /></a></div>';    
    }
    $output .= '</div></div></div></div>';
    return $output;  
}  

add_shortcode('partners', 'partners');
```

Comment: your title is a bit confusing, not sure what it has to do with your actual question. that said, this isn't really a WordPress issue. you're targeting each slider instance with a general class selector- `".partners-slider"`. give each of your sliders a unique ID and target that instead.

Comment: It's generating a unique ID now but not working as well. The print_partners_scripts() function print js code only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values by adding your own filter. Proof of concept:

```
add_filter(
  'my_filter',
  function() {
    return array(1,2,3);
  }
);

function print_partners_scripts() {
  $args = apply_filters('my_filter',null);
  var_dump($args);
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'print_partners_scripts' );
```

Where you to register and enqueue your script instead of echoing it directly to the page, you could use [`wp_localize-script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to pass information to it.

Comment: That sounds good ;) Gonna check this soon, Big Thanks ! Any alternative will be really appreciated, just for my knowledge ;)

Comment: I want to set options in shortcode. Is this gonna work with add_filter?

Comment: It should. Your shortcode should pocesss before the footer.